# How do I match IDs in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello i'm building React web application that has CRUD for "Fleet car manager".  I'm using axios libraries to get/post requests to and from my api controller written in Spring Boot. I've builded Table where i want to render data i got from 2 axios get methods `/car` [Data from /car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsi2F.png) and `/company` [Data from /company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC8Uk.png).

This is how i render data from `/car`

```
 {this.state.cars.map(car =>
                                <tr key={car.idCar}>
                                    <td>{car.carBrand}</td>
                                    <td>{car.carModel}</td>
                                    <td>{car.carManufactureYear}</td>
                                    <td>{car.carType}</td>
                                    <td>{car.engineCapacity}</td>
                                    <td>{car.enginePower}</td>
                                    <td>{car.plateNumber}</td>
                                    <td>{car.id_company}</td>
                                    <td styles="text-align: center, display: inline-block">
```

Works just fine [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAApp.png)

Now i want to replace this `car.id_company` with name of company which i got from `axios.get(localhost:8080/company)`

Any tips how to do this?

Comment: You need a data store like Redux and that is where you make your modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have get the info from `/company`, just make an object by using `reduce` to store the mapping info.

```
const mapping = res.reduce((idNameMapping, elem) => {
        idNameMapping[id] = elem.name 
        return idNameMapping
} , {})

{this.state.cars.map(car =>
             //more on top
             <td>{mapping[car.id_company]}</td>
             // more down below
```

Comment: I've updated my axios get method like you said. https://imgur.com/a/maxcsEH added mapping to `this.state`. When I use console.log for idNameMapping it gives me something like this : https://imgur.com/a/0yGZRvW but doesn't show name in table. Can you tell me what did i do wrong?

Comment: @JackB I think you should use ```companies.reduce``` first since ```this.setState``` is async. There is no guarantee for the running order. After that, you use ```this.setState({companies, mapping})```.  to set back the state

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it by creating a function, you need to pass a value and return filtered first data to get the name.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

  const [company, setCompany] = useState([
    {
      idCompany: 1,
      name: "xyz",
    },
    {
      idCompany: 2,
      name: "Abc",
    }
  ]);

  const [car, setCar] = useState([
    {
      idCar: 1,
      id_company: 2,
      name: "A"
    },
    {
      idCar: 2,
      id_company: 1,
      name: "B"
    }
  ])

  // filter company name and get data from frist data
  const companyName = (id) => {
    let tempCompany = company.filter((c) => {
      return c.idCompany === id
    })
    console.log(tempCompany[0]);
    return tempCompany[0].name;
  }
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Car name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
      {car.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{companyName(item.id_company)}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      })}
    </table>
  )
}
export default MyComponent
```

Comment: I don't know why my answer got negative mark,

Comment: It's only a minor problem with your example, but your method is really inefficient. Best practice for this use case is to create a `{ [key]: value }` pair like in @tcf_01's answer or `Map` when things start getting big. And let's say we were in a situation where we couldn't create a key/value pair, but we still only want to find 1 match. In that situation you still probably wouldn't want to use `filter` because it goes through the entire array. You would ideally loop through the array until you found a match, then stop the loop and return the matched value.